# Autopilot GKE cluster insufficient cpu/mem

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy an Autopilot cluster on GKE however I am getting insufficient CPU/memory errors as below when trying to deploy a Pod. Kubectl get nodes returns 3 nodes, each with about 0.5GB free cpu and same for memory so quite small. I am trying to run a GPU heavy job so I expect GKE to scale up however it fails saying insufficient resources. What am I doing wrong?

````
  Warning  FailedScheduling   27m (x5 over 31m)      gke.io/optimize-utilization-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient cpu, 2 Insufficient memory.
  Warning  FailedScheduling   26m                    gke.io/optimize-utilization-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/not-ready: }, that the pod didn't tolerate, 2 Insufficient cpu, 2 Insufficient memory.
  Normal   TriggeredScaleUp   26m                    cluster-autoscaler                     pod triggered scale-up: [{https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/picdmo-342711/zones/us-central1-c/instanceGroups/gk3-picdmo-nap-1wcisjk4-2ba03e97-grp 0->1 (max: 1000)}]
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  25m (x6 over 30m)      cluster-autoscaler                     pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 1 Insufficient cpu, 1 Insufficient memory, 2 in backoff after failed scale-up
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  20m (x14 over 21m)     cluster-autoscaler                     pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 2 Insufficient cpu, 1 Insufficient memory
  Normal   TriggeredScaleUp   15m                    cluster-autoscaler                     pod triggered scale-up: [{https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/picdmo-342711/zones/us-central1-c/instanceGroups/gk3-picdmo-nap-xt7d8ijc-37c84d94-grp 0->1 (max: 1000)}]
  Warning  FailedScaleUp      15m (x5 over 31m)      cluster-autoscaler                     Node scale up in zones us-central1-c associated with this pod failed: GCE quota exceeded. Pod is at risk of not being scheduled.
  Warning  FailedScheduling   15m (x6 over 20m)      gke.io/optimize-utilization-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient memory, 4 Insufficient cpu.
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  14m (x2 over 15m)      cluster-autoscaler                     (combined from similar events): pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 2 in backoff after failed scale-up, 2 Insufficient cpu, 1 Insufficient memory
  Warning  FailedScheduling   13m (x2 over 14m)      gke.io/optimize-utilization-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {ToBeDeletedByClusterAutoscaler: 1660665555}, that the pod didn't tolerate, 3 Insufficient cpu, 3 Insufficient memory.
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  4m50s (x135 over 29m)  cluster-autoscaler                     pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 1 Insufficient cpu, 1 Insufficient memory
  Warning  FailedScheduling   92s (x17 over 25m)     gke.io/optimize-utilization-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient cpu, 3 Insufficient memory.```

apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  generateName: asd-job-
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: asd
          image: gcr.io/-342711/-job:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args: ["-c", "echo"]
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "16000Mi"
              cpu: "8000m"
            limits:
              memory: "32000Mi"
              cpu: "16000m"
              nvidia.com/gpu: 2
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
````

Answer (score 2):

```
us-central1-c associated with this pod failed: GCE quota exceeded
```

From the 7th line.

Possibly a quota issue. Check IAM & admin > Quotas

Comment: Any idea how to tell which resource exceeded? I've raised memory,cpu and ip address count, same error.

Comment: Check IAM & admin > Quotas